# Searching for dates within the date range in a multiValued field

Tags: solr

I'm having troubles searching for documents which date fall within the range I specify in my query.

The schema configuration is the following

```
<field name="dates" type="rdates" stored="true" />
<fieldType name="rdates" class="solr.DateRangeField" multiValued="true" />
```

These are the documents I have indexed in Solr

Query: `q=dates:*`

```
{
"responseHeader":{
    "params":{
    "q":"dates:*",
    "_":"1518809837624"}},
"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "dates":["[2015-12-31 TO 2016-01-01]"],
        "_version_":1592586045307748352},
    {
        "id":2,
        "dates":["[2015 TO 2017]",
        "[2013 TO 2015]"],
        "_version_":1592595675256717312}]
}}
```

And these are the documents that match the user's query:

Query: `fq={!field f=dates op=Within}[2012 TO 2016]&q=dates:*`

```
{
"responseHeader":{
    "params":{
    "q":"*:*",
    "fq":"{!field f=dates op=Within}[2012 TO 2016]",
    "_":"1518808413748"}},
"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "dates":["[2015-12-31 TO 2016-01-01]"],
        "_version_":1592586045307748352}]
}}
```

As I understand, the document with the ID 2 should match given that one of the values in the dates field match with my query.

Indeed, changing the document ID=2 to have only the value `[2013 TO 2015]` in the dates field, it matches my query.

Query: `fq={!field f=dates op=Within}[2012 TO 2016]&q=dates:*`

```
{
"responseHeader":{
    "params":{
    "q":"dates:*",
    "fq":"{!field f=dates op=Within}[2012 TO 2016]",
    "_":"1518808413748"}},
"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "dates":["[2015-12-31 TO 2016-01-01]"],
        "_version_":1592586045307748352},
    {
        "id":2,
        "dates":["[2013 TO 2015]"],
        "_version_":1592597631061721088}]
}}
```

How should I query for documents that fall within the range specified by the query?

Answer (score 0):

Same code and configuration, different days, it worked

I think my computer doesn't like to work Friday afternoons.